# When modeling a CouchDB object in Backbone, should there be a 1-1 relationship between a model and database?

Tags: backbone.js, couchdb, pouchdb

When modeling a `CouchDB` object in `Backbone`, should there be a **1-1** relationship between a **backbone model** and a **CouchDB database**?

Currently, my models are around database documents and not a whole database. I am also using `PouchDB` to communicate witch `CouchDB`.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB dev here. Would not make them match 1:1. put all docs that belong to an app into a single database and give them a `type` field. Use a view to get all docs per type (or put the `type` as the prefix of the `_id` and use `_all_docs`/`allDocs()`) and have all docs of a type match the backbone model 1:1).

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of research and experimentation I came to the following conclusions.

You should use collections to model your database if your database holds related documents OR if you are using PouchDB.

Here is why:
1) A collection that holds related models is analogous to a a database that holds related documents.
2) Most importantly, **if you are using PouchDB, you should use a collection to model your database**. By doing so you can tie a collection to a PouchDB object and take advantage of backbone's events when the database or collection changes.

The alternative is to pass a reference to a PouchDB instance to each model.